# How to prevent Harvard style (agsm) referencing from causing bibliography URLs to spill across two columns?

Tags: bibliographies, formatting, citing, overleaf, harvard-style

I would like for my citation style to be Harvard.

I am using the following:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[comma]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

foo \citep{vitz_history_2016}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

Citation from example in the `.bib` file:

```
@online{vitz_history_2016,
    year = {2016},
    title = {History of the Periodic Table},
    url = {https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Ancillary_Materials/Exemplars_and_Case_Studies/Exemplars/Culture/History_of_the_Periodic_Table},
    titleaddon = {Chemistry {LibreTexts}},
    author = {Vitz, Ed and Moore, John and Shorb, Justin and Prat-Resina, Xavier and Wendorff, Tim and Hahn, Adam},
    urldate = {2019-11-25},
    date = {2016-05-26},
    langid = {english},
    file = {fname}
}
```

In a two column layout this produces:
[image: agsm]

I normally create documents using `\cite{author}` and `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}` and so by including `\usepackage{url}` URLs are displayed correctly:
[image: ieeetran]

I would like for the same reference to appear as the second example but use a Harvard style citation as in the first example.

**Any help would be much appreciated!**

Comment: Have you tried loading the `xurl` package instead of the `url` package?

Comment: Please show the bib entry in question. In particular, how is the URL string marked up?

Comment: The fact that the `M` in `Ancillary_Materials` appears as a subscript makes me think that the URL is for some reason not typeset with `\url` (as one would usually expect), but instead as normal text. This is particularly odd since your load the `url` package, which defines `\url`. When I try to run your code I get an error, since the style `IEEEtran` is incompatible with `natbib`. If you want to use `natbib` you need to load the style `IEEEtranN` (but you should know that `natbib` should not be used for IEEE submissions).

Comment: Hi @Mico, I've added the `.bib` for the example given. I just tried `xurl` but it didn't seem to make any difference to the formatting of the reference.

Comment: Hi @moewe, This is not meant for any submissions. I am trying to create a simple two column layout with a Harvard referencing style for someone else to use. I am definitely not the most knowledgeable when it comes to LaTeX; I am simply adapting what I would normally use. Any help in getting the desired formatting would be **greatly** appreciated.

Comment: @moewe - The `agsm` bibliography style is quite old. While it does recognize a field called `url`, it doesn't encase its contents automatically in a true `\url` directive. (By "true", I mean something akin to what's provided by the `url` and `xurl` packages.) That's why the OP is getting, say, subscript-M instead of `_M`. The remedy is to manually encase any URL strings in `\url{...}` directives.

Comment: @Mico  `agsm` uses `\harvardurl` around URLs, which `natbib` defines as `\newcommand\harvardurl[1]{\textbf{URL:} \textit{#1}}`, so one might want to try something like `\renewcommand\harvardurl{\textbf{URL:} \url}`. I would try to avoid putting `\url{...}` around the URL in the `url` field if at all possible.

Comment: @moewe - Great suggestion! :-) I'll incorporate it in my answer.

Comment: If it is only two-column typesetting you are after, you could also use `\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}` instead of `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}`. I usually recommend to avoid customised publisher classes if one is not submitting to the publisher, since those classes can sometimes be harder to customise or may load package that one doesn't need or that are incompatible with packages one would like to use. (BTW: The 'you should know' in my comment above meant 'I should tell you, if I recommend `IEEEtranN`', not that you should know without being told.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seem to be several issues.

- Since you're using the `IEEEtran` document class, using the `IEEEtran` bibliography style along with the `natbib` package should be used exclusively in conjunction with the `\cite` and `\citep` commands; both will generate numeric-style citation call-outs. `\citet` isn't really usable with the `IEEEtran` bibliography style.
- If you wish to use the `natbib` package along with the `IEEEtran` document class, you should probably be using the `IEEEtranN` bibliography style. (The `N` in `IEEEtranN` stands for `natbib`...) With this setup, `\cite` and `\citep` will still produce numeric-style call-outs, but `\citet` now "works" too, in the sense that it creates author-**number** style citation call-outs. Try as you might, though, you won't get this setup to produce author-**year** style, aka "harvard-style" and "agsm-style", citation call-outs.

  That said, I will echo @moewe's comment: Most (all?!) journals that require the use of the `IEEEtran` document class employ numeric style citation call-outs; they will probably reject submissions that employ author-number or author-year style citation call-outs.
- Just in case this wasn't a typo: The proper syntax is `\citep{<some_key>}`, not `\citep(<some_key>)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@online{vitz_history_2016,
    year = {2016},
    title = {History of the Periodic Table},
    url = {https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Ancillary_Materials/Exemplars_and_Case_Studies/Exemplars/Culture/History_of_the_Periodic_Table},
    titleaddon = {Chemistry {LibreTexts}},
    author = {Vitz, Ed and Moore, John and Shorb, Justin and Prat-Resina, Xavier and Wendorff, Tim and Hahn, Adam},
    urldate = {2019-11-25},
    date = {2016-05-26},
    langid = {english},
    file = {fname}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[numbers,comma]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN} % not 'IEEEtran'
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} % just for this example

\begin{document}
foo \citep{vitz_history_2016} % not "\citep(author)"

bar \citet{vitz_history_2016}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: I can actually reproduce the awful-looking non-linebroken URL string, with subscripts in place of underscores, shown in your first screenshot if I replace `\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}` with `\bibliographystyle{agsm}`. The `agsm` style is quite old and and uses a macro called `\harvardurl`, which does *not* take the same precautions as `\url` does when typesetting URL strings; these precautions pertain to TeX-special characters, such as `_` and `%`, which may occur in a URL string. (Many thanks to @moewe for pointing this out to me!)

If you *must* use the `agsm` bibliography style, then, there are two ways to proceed: First, you could provide the instruction

```
\renewcommand\harvardurl{\textbf{URL:} \url}
```

after `\bibliographystyle{agsm}`. Second, you could change

```
url = {https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Ancillary_Materials/Exemplars_and_Case_Studies/Exemplars/Culture/History_of_the_Periodic_Table},
```

to

```
url = {\url{https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Ancillary_Materials/Exemplars_and_Case_Studies/Exemplars/Culture/History_of_the_Periodic_Table}},
```

Of course, both methods assume that you've loaded a suitable package -- `url` and `xurl` come to mind -- that defines a "real" `\url` macro.

Incidentally, if you wish to use the `agsm` bibliography style, you should load the `har2nat` package, not the `natbib` package directly. Why? The `agsm` bib style is part of the [harvard](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/harvard) citation management package, which comes with some specialized commands. The `har2nat` package (a) loads the `natbib` package and (b) "translates" the `harvard`-specific macros into macros recognized by the `natbib` package. This is especially useful if you wish to use the `hyperref` package in your document: `hyperref` is fully compatible with the `natbib` package, but less so with the `harvard` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{mybib.bib}
@online{vitz_history_2016,
    year = {2016},
    title = {History of the Periodic Table},
    url = {\url{https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Ancillary_Materials/Exemplars_and_Case_Studies/Exemplars/Culture/History_of_the_Periodic_Table}},
    titleaddon = {Chemistry {LibreTexts}},
    author = {Vitz, Ed and Moore, John and Shorb, Justin and Prat-Resina, Xavier and Wendorff, Tim and Hahn, Adam},
    urldate = {2019-11-25},
    date = {2016-05-26},
    langid = {english},
    file = {fname}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{har2nat} % not 'natbib' directly
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\usepackage{xurl}
\usepackage[colorlinks,allcolors=blue]{hyperref} 

\begin{document}
foo \citep{vitz_history_2016} % not "\citep(author)"

bar \citet{vitz_history_2016}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed response.  I have used `har2nat`, `xurl`, and `agsm` which has produced the desired formatting. To reiterate my previous comment, this isn't meant for submission but just a simple to use template to pass on to another who's LaTeX ability is even more limited than mine! I have corrected the typo.